# names.arg not following my command

Tags: r, matrix, plot, boxplot

I am boxplotting a matrix according to a "levels" column

```
col1   Tag
123     B
13      A
2       C
1321    A
321     B
321     D
321     A
53      C
```

I am currently using the following command for plotting

```
boxplot(mydata ~ mydata$Tag, main = mytitle, names.arg=c("group1","group2","group3","group4")
```

The problem is that I am getting boxplots with A,B,C and D instead of group1, group2, group3 and group4.

This is very basic but I am rather surprised why names.arg isn't working!

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

Comment: well, for one thing there is no `names.arg` argument for `boxplot`.  Try `names` instead

Comment: Sorry, the comment you just made is not a comment. It is an ANSWER :) Thanks buddy